# CRC8 Slice-by-4 algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, crc, crc8

I am in need of a highly optimized CRC8 algorithm. My goal is to develop a Slice-by-4 solution as known from CRC16 / CRC32. I want to keep the code as close to the solution which I am using for CRC16 posted below.

**Functions to generate the CRC LookUp-Table:**

```
void crcspeed16_genTable(crcfn16 crcfn, uint16_t table[8][256]) {
    uint16_t crc;

    /* generate CRCs for all single byte sequences */
    for (int n = 0; n < 256; n++) {
        table[0][n] = crcfn(0, &n, 1);
    }

    /* generate nested CRC table for future slice-by-8 lookup */
    for (int n = 0; n < 256; n++) {
        crc = table[0][n];
        for (int k = 1; k < 8; k++) {
            crc = table[0][(crc >> 8) & 0xff] ^ (crc << 8);
            table[k][n] = crc;
        }
    }
}


uint16_t crc16(uint16_t crc, const void *in_data, uint64_t len) {
    const uint8_t *data = (const uint8_t*) in_data;
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        crc = crc ^ (data[i] << 8);
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (crc & 0x8000) {
                crc = (crc << 1) ^ CRC16_POLYNOMINAL;
            } else {
                crc = (crc << 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return crc;
}
```

**Call to generate the table:**

```
crcspeed16_genTable(crc16, crc16_LUT);
```

**Function to generate the CRC16 based on the Slice-by-4 solution:**

```
uint16_t crc16_slice4(const void *buf, size_t len, uint16_t initialValue, uint16_t XOR_OUT) {
    uint16_t crc = initialValue;
    unsigned char *next = (unsigned char *)buf;

    // process individual bytes until we reach an 8-byte aligned pointer
    while (len && ((uintptr_t)next & 7) != 0) {
        crc = crc16_LUT[0][((crc >> 8) ^ *next++) & 0xff] ^ (crc << 8);
        len--;
    }

    // fast middle processing, 4 bytes (aligned!) per loop */
    while (len >= 4) {
        uint32_t n = *(uint32_t *)next;
        crc = crc16_LUT[3][(n & 0xff) ^ ((crc >> 8) & 0xff)] ^
              crc16_LUT[2][((n >> 8) & 0xff) ^ (crc & 0xff)] ^
              crc16_LUT[1][(n >> 16) & 0xff] ^
              crc16_LUT[0][n >> 24];

        next += 4;
        len -= 4;
    }

    // process remaining bytes (can't be larger than 8)
    while (len) {
        crc = crc16_LUT[0][((crc >> 8) ^ *next++) & 0xff] ^ (crc << 8);
        len--;
    }

    return crc ^ XOR_OUT;
}
```

My aim is to adapt the algorithm to be working for CRC8 and CRC4. What I have managed so far is to change the LUT-Generator to be generating a valid first row of the LUT and process a valid CRC based on this LUT data. I am failing to adapt the middle part to calculate and utilize the full potential of the CRC table.

**Adapted functions (not fully functional) for CRC8:**
***Table generation:***

```
void crcspeed8_genTable(crcfn8 crcfn, uint8_t table[8][256]) {
    uint16_t crc;

    /* generate CRCs for all single byte sequences */
    for (int n = 0; n < 256; n++) {
        table[0][n] = crcfn(0, &n, 1);
    }

    /* generate nested CRC table for future slice-by-8 lookup */
    for (int n = 0; n < 256; n++) {
        crc = table[0][n];
        for (int k = 1; k < 8; k++) {
            //crc = table[0][crc] ^ crc;
            crc = table[0][(crc >> 4) & 0x0f] ^ (crc << 4);               
            table[k][n] = crc;
        }
    }
}

uint8_t crc8(uint8_t crc, const void *in_data, uint64_t len) {
    const uint8_t *data = (const uint8_t*) in_data;
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        //crc = crc ^ (data[i] << 8);
        crc = crc ^ data[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (crc & 0x80) {
                crc = (crc << 1) ^ CRC8_POLYNOMINAL;
            } else {
                crc = (crc << 1);
            }
        }
    }

    return crc;
}
```

***CRC calculation:***

```
uint8_t crc8_slice4(const void *buf, size_t len, uint8_t initialValue, uint8_t XOR_OUT) {
    uint8_t crc = initialValue;
    unsigned char *next = (unsigned char *)buf;

    // process individual bytes until we reach an 8-byte aligned pointer
    while (len && ((uintptr_t)next & 7) != 0) {
        printf("\nAlign processing");
        crc = crc8_LUT[0][crc ^ *next++];
        len--;
    }

    //fast middle processing, 4 bytes (aligned!) per loop
    while (len >= 4) {
        printf("\nSlice processing");
        uint32_t n = *(uint32_t *)next;

        //This part should be adopted to work for CRC8
        /*crc = crc8_LUT[3][(n & 0xff) ^ crc] ^
              crc8_LUT[2][(n >> 8) & 0xff] ^ 
              crc8_LUT[1][(n >> 16) & 0xff] ^
              crc8_LUT[0][n >> 24]; */

            uint32_t n0 = (n & 0xFF) ^ crc;
            uint32_t n1 = (n >>  8) & 0xFF;
            uint32_t n2 = (n >> 16) & 0xFF;
            uint32_t n3 = (n >> 24);

            //Working multi step for CRC 4 only using first row of LUT
            uint8_t crc0 = crc8_LUT[0][crc  ^ n0];
            uint8_t crc1 = crc8_LUT[0][crc0 ^ n1];
            uint8_t crc2 = crc8_LUT[0][crc1 ^ n2];
            uint8_t crc3 = crc8_LUT[0][crc2 ^ n3];
            crc = crc3;

        next += 4;
        len -= 4;
    }

    // process remaining bytes (can't be larger than 8)
    while (len) {
        printf("\nRemain processing");
        crc = crc8_LUT[0][crc ^ *next++];
        len--;
    }
    return crc ^ XOR_OUT;
}
```

I tried to change the functions to be working for CRC8 but I can't figure out the middle part. A solution explaining the general approach to generating Look-Up-Tables for various CRCs (4/8/16/24/32...) would also be highly appreciated.
Thanks for hopefully pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide your polynomial, initial value, or final exclusive or. With those (and that the CRC in your case is not reflected), you can use [crcany](https://github.com/madler/crcany) to generate the code for you.

Here is an example for little-endian slice-by-4:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define table_byte table_word[0]

static uint8_t const table_word[][256] = {
   {0xbd, 0x92, 0xe3, 0xcc, 0x01, 0x2e, 0x5f, 0x70, 0xea, 0xc5, 0xb4, 0x9b, 0x56,
    0x79, 0x08, 0x27, 0x13, 0x3c, 0x4d, 0x62, 0xaf, 0x80, 0xf1, 0xde, 0x44, 0x6b,
    0x1a, 0x35, 0xf8, 0xd7, 0xa6, 0x89, 0xce, 0xe1, 0x90, 0xbf, 0x72, 0x5d, 0x2c,
    0x03, 0x99, 0xb6, 0xc7, 0xe8, 0x25, 0x0a, 0x7b, 0x54, 0x60, 0x4f, 0x3e, 0x11,
    0xdc, 0xf3, 0x82, 0xad, 0x37, 0x18, 0x69, 0x46, 0x8b, 0xa4, 0xd5, 0xfa, 0x5b,
    0x74, 0x05, 0x2a, 0xe7, 0xc8, 0xb9, 0x96, 0x0c, 0x23, 0x52, 0x7d, 0xb0, 0x9f,
    0xee, 0xc1, 0xf5, 0xda, 0xab, 0x84, 0x49, 0x66, 0x17, 0x38, 0xa2, 0x8d, 0xfc,
    0xd3, 0x1e, 0x31, 0x40, 0x6f, 0x28, 0x07, 0x76, 0x59, 0x94, 0xbb, 0xca, 0xe5,
    0x7f, 0x50, 0x21, 0x0e, 0xc3, 0xec, 0x9d, 0xb2, 0x86, 0xa9, 0xd8, 0xf7, 0x3a,
    0x15, 0x64, 0x4b, 0xd1, 0xfe, 0x8f, 0xa0, 0x6d, 0x42, 0x33, 0x1c, 0x5e, 0x71,
    0x00, 0x2f, 0xe2, 0xcd, 0xbc, 0x93, 0x09, 0x26, 0x57, 0x78, 0xb5, 0x9a, 0xeb,
    0xc4, 0xf0, 0xdf, 0xae, 0x81, 0x4c, 0x63, 0x12, 0x3d, 0xa7, 0x88, 0xf9, 0xd6,
    0x1b, 0x34, 0x45, 0x6a, 0x2d, 0x02, 0x73, 0x5c, 0x91, 0xbe, 0xcf, 0xe0, 0x7a,
    0x55, 0x24, 0x0b, 0xc6, 0xe9, 0x98, 0xb7, 0x83, 0xac, 0xdd, 0xf2, 0x3f, 0x10,
    0x61, 0x4e, 0xd4, 0xfb, 0x8a, 0xa5, 0x68, 0x47, 0x36, 0x19, 0xb8, 0x97, 0xe6,
    0xc9, 0x04, 0x2b, 0x5a, 0x75, 0xef, 0xc0, 0xb1, 0x9e, 0x53, 0x7c, 0x0d, 0x22,
    0x16, 0x39, 0x48, 0x67, 0xaa, 0x85, 0xf4, 0xdb, 0x41, 0x6e, 0x1f, 0x30, 0xfd,
    0xd2, 0xa3, 0x8c, 0xcb, 0xe4, 0x95, 0xba, 0x77, 0x58, 0x29, 0x06, 0x9c, 0xb3,
    0xc2, 0xed, 0x20, 0x0f, 0x7e, 0x51, 0x65, 0x4a, 0x3b, 0x14, 0xd9, 0xf6, 0x87,
    0xa8, 0x32, 0x1d, 0x6c, 0x43, 0x8e, 0xa1, 0xd0, 0xff},
   {0xfa, 0x13, 0x07, 0xee, 0x2f, 0xc6, 0xd2, 0x3b, 0x7f, 0x96, 0x82, 0x6b, 0xaa,
    0x43, 0x57, 0xbe, 0xdf, 0x36, 0x22, 0xcb, 0x0a, 0xe3, 0xf7, 0x1e, 0x5a, 0xb3,
    0xa7, 0x4e, 0x8f, 0x66, 0x72, 0x9b, 0xb0, 0x59, 0x4d, 0xa4, 0x65, 0x8c, 0x98,
    0x71, 0x35, 0xdc, 0xc8, 0x21, 0xe0, 0x09, 0x1d, 0xf4, 0x95, 0x7c, 0x68, 0x81,
    0x40, 0xa9, 0xbd, 0x54, 0x10, 0xf9, 0xed, 0x04, 0xc5, 0x2c, 0x38, 0xd1, 0x6e,
    0x87, 0x93, 0x7a, 0xbb, 0x52, 0x46, 0xaf, 0xeb, 0x02, 0x16, 0xff, 0x3e, 0xd7,
    0xc3, 0x2a, 0x4b, 0xa2, 0xb6, 0x5f, 0x9e, 0x77, 0x63, 0x8a, 0xce, 0x27, 0x33,
    0xda, 0x1b, 0xf2, 0xe6, 0x0f, 0x24, 0xcd, 0xd9, 0x30, 0xf1, 0x18, 0x0c, 0xe5,
    0xa1, 0x48, 0x5c, 0xb5, 0x74, 0x9d, 0x89, 0x60, 0x01, 0xe8, 0xfc, 0x15, 0xd4,
    0x3d, 0x29, 0xc0, 0x84, 0x6d, 0x79, 0x90, 0x51, 0xb8, 0xac, 0x45, 0xfd, 0x14,
    0x00, 0xe9, 0x28, 0xc1, 0xd5, 0x3c, 0x78, 0x91, 0x85, 0x6c, 0xad, 0x44, 0x50,
    0xb9, 0xd8, 0x31, 0x25, 0xcc, 0x0d, 0xe4, 0xf0, 0x19, 0x5d, 0xb4, 0xa0, 0x49,
    0x88, 0x61, 0x75, 0x9c, 0xb7, 0x5e, 0x4a, 0xa3, 0x62, 0x8b, 0x9f, 0x76, 0x32,
    0xdb, 0xcf, 0x26, 0xe7, 0x0e, 0x1a, 0xf3, 0x92, 0x7b, 0x6f, 0x86, 0x47, 0xae,
    0xba, 0x53, 0x17, 0xfe, 0xea, 0x03, 0xc2, 0x2b, 0x3f, 0xd6, 0x69, 0x80, 0x94,
    0x7d, 0xbc, 0x55, 0x41, 0xa8, 0xec, 0x05, 0x11, 0xf8, 0x39, 0xd0, 0xc4, 0x2d,
    0x4c, 0xa5, 0xb1, 0x58, 0x99, 0x70, 0x64, 0x8d, 0xc9, 0x20, 0x34, 0xdd, 0x1c,
    0xf5, 0xe1, 0x08, 0x23, 0xca, 0xde, 0x37, 0xf6, 0x1f, 0x0b, 0xe2, 0xa6, 0x4f,
    0x5b, 0xb2, 0x73, 0x9a, 0x8e, 0x67, 0x06, 0xef, 0xfb, 0x12, 0xd3, 0x3a, 0x2e,
    0xc7, 0x83, 0x6a, 0x7e, 0x97, 0x56, 0xbf, 0xab, 0x42},
   {0xd1, 0xdf, 0xcd, 0xc3, 0xe9, 0xe7, 0xf5, 0xfb, 0xa1, 0xaf, 0xbd, 0xb3, 0x99,
    0x97, 0x85, 0x8b, 0x31, 0x3f, 0x2d, 0x23, 0x09, 0x07, 0x15, 0x1b, 0x41, 0x4f,
    0x5d, 0x53, 0x79, 0x77, 0x65, 0x6b, 0x3e, 0x30, 0x22, 0x2c, 0x06, 0x08, 0x1a,
    0x14, 0x4e, 0x40, 0x52, 0x5c, 0x76, 0x78, 0x6a, 0x64, 0xde, 0xd0, 0xc2, 0xcc,
    0xe6, 0xe8, 0xfa, 0xf4, 0xae, 0xa0, 0xb2, 0xbc, 0x96, 0x98, 0x8a, 0x84, 0x20,
    0x2e, 0x3c, 0x32, 0x18, 0x16, 0x04, 0x0a, 0x50, 0x5e, 0x4c, 0x42, 0x68, 0x66,
    0x74, 0x7a, 0xc0, 0xce, 0xdc, 0xd2, 0xf8, 0xf6, 0xe4, 0xea, 0xb0, 0xbe, 0xac,
    0xa2, 0x88, 0x86, 0x94, 0x9a, 0xcf, 0xc1, 0xd3, 0xdd, 0xf7, 0xf9, 0xeb, 0xe5,
    0xbf, 0xb1, 0xa3, 0xad, 0x87, 0x89, 0x9b, 0x95, 0x2f, 0x21, 0x33, 0x3d, 0x17,
    0x19, 0x0b, 0x05, 0x5f, 0x51, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x67, 0x69, 0x7b, 0x75, 0x1c, 0x12,
    0x00, 0x0e, 0x24, 0x2a, 0x38, 0x36, 0x6c, 0x62, 0x70, 0x7e, 0x54, 0x5a, 0x48,
    0x46, 0xfc, 0xf2, 0xe0, 0xee, 0xc4, 0xca, 0xd8, 0xd6, 0x8c, 0x82, 0x90, 0x9e,
    0xb4, 0xba, 0xa8, 0xa6, 0xf3, 0xfd, 0xef, 0xe1, 0xcb, 0xc5, 0xd7, 0xd9, 0x83,
    0x8d, 0x9f, 0x91, 0xbb, 0xb5, 0xa7, 0xa9, 0x13, 0x1d, 0x0f, 0x01, 0x2b, 0x25,
    0x37, 0x39, 0x63, 0x6d, 0x7f, 0x71, 0x5b, 0x55, 0x47, 0x49, 0xed, 0xe3, 0xf1,
    0xff, 0xd5, 0xdb, 0xc9, 0xc7, 0x9d, 0x93, 0x81, 0x8f, 0xa5, 0xab, 0xb9, 0xb7,
    0x0d, 0x03, 0x11, 0x1f, 0x35, 0x3b, 0x29, 0x27, 0x7d, 0x73, 0x61, 0x6f, 0x45,
    0x4b, 0x59, 0x57, 0x02, 0x0c, 0x1e, 0x10, 0x3a, 0x34, 0x26, 0x28, 0x72, 0x7c,
    0x6e, 0x60, 0x4a, 0x44, 0x56, 0x58, 0xe2, 0xec, 0xfe, 0xf0, 0xda, 0xd4, 0xc6,
    0xc8, 0x92, 0x9c, 0x8e, 0x80, 0xaa, 0xa4, 0xb6, 0xb8},
   {0x84, 0x31, 0xc1, 0x74, 0x0e, 0xbb, 0x4b, 0xfe, 0xbf, 0x0a, 0xfa, 0x4f, 0x35,
    0x80, 0x70, 0xc5, 0xf2, 0x47, 0xb7, 0x02, 0x78, 0xcd, 0x3d, 0x88, 0xc9, 0x7c,
    0x8c, 0x39, 0x43, 0xf6, 0x06, 0xb3, 0x68, 0xdd, 0x2d, 0x98, 0xe2, 0x57, 0xa7,
    0x12, 0x53, 0xe6, 0x16, 0xa3, 0xd9, 0x6c, 0x9c, 0x29, 0x1e, 0xab, 0x5b, 0xee,
    0x94, 0x21, 0xd1, 0x64, 0x25, 0x90, 0x60, 0xd5, 0xaf, 0x1a, 0xea, 0x5f, 0x73,
    0xc6, 0x36, 0x83, 0xf9, 0x4c, 0xbc, 0x09, 0x48, 0xfd, 0x0d, 0xb8, 0xc2, 0x77,
    0x87, 0x32, 0x05, 0xb0, 0x40, 0xf5, 0x8f, 0x3a, 0xca, 0x7f, 0x3e, 0x8b, 0x7b,
    0xce, 0xb4, 0x01, 0xf1, 0x44, 0x9f, 0x2a, 0xda, 0x6f, 0x15, 0xa0, 0x50, 0xe5,
    0xa4, 0x11, 0xe1, 0x54, 0x2e, 0x9b, 0x6b, 0xde, 0xe9, 0x5c, 0xac, 0x19, 0x63,
    0xd6, 0x26, 0x93, 0xd2, 0x67, 0x97, 0x22, 0x58, 0xed, 0x1d, 0xa8, 0x45, 0xf0,
    0x00, 0xb5, 0xcf, 0x7a, 0x8a, 0x3f, 0x7e, 0xcb, 0x3b, 0x8e, 0xf4, 0x41, 0xb1,
    0x04, 0x33, 0x86, 0x76, 0xc3, 0xb9, 0x0c, 0xfc, 0x49, 0x08, 0xbd, 0x4d, 0xf8,
    0x82, 0x37, 0xc7, 0x72, 0xa9, 0x1c, 0xec, 0x59, 0x23, 0x96, 0x66, 0xd3, 0x92,
    0x27, 0xd7, 0x62, 0x18, 0xad, 0x5d, 0xe8, 0xdf, 0x6a, 0x9a, 0x2f, 0x55, 0xe0,
    0x10, 0xa5, 0xe4, 0x51, 0xa1, 0x14, 0x6e, 0xdb, 0x2b, 0x9e, 0xb2, 0x07, 0xf7,
    0x42, 0x38, 0x8d, 0x7d, 0xc8, 0x89, 0x3c, 0xcc, 0x79, 0x03, 0xb6, 0x46, 0xf3,
    0xc4, 0x71, 0x81, 0x34, 0x4e, 0xfb, 0x0b, 0xbe, 0xff, 0x4a, 0xba, 0x0f, 0x75,
    0xc0, 0x30, 0x85, 0x5e, 0xeb, 0x1b, 0xae, 0xd4, 0x61, 0x91, 0x24, 0x65, 0xd0,
    0x20, 0x95, 0xef, 0x5a, 0xaa, 0x1f, 0x28, 0x9d, 0x6d, 0xd8, 0xa2, 0x17, 0xe7,
    0x52, 0x13, 0xa6, 0x56, 0xe3, 0x99, 0x2c, 0xdc, 0x69}
};
    
// This code assumes that integers are stored little-endian.

uint8_t crc8autosar_word(uint8_t crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    unsigned char const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0;
    while (len && ((ptrdiff_t)data & 0x3)) {
        len--;
        crc = table_byte[crc ^ *data++];
    }
    size_t n = len >> 2;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        uint32_t word = crc ^ ((uint32_t const *)data)[i];
        crc = table_word[3][word & 0xff] ^
              table_word[2][(word >> 8) & 0xff] ^
              table_word[1][(word >> 16) & 0xff] ^
              table_word[0][word >> 24];
    }
    data += n << 2;
    len &= 3;
    while (len) {
        len--;
        crc = table_byte[crc ^ *data++];
    }
    return crc;
}
```

The convention for this code is that when called with `mem == NULL`, `crc` is ignored and the initial CRC, i.e. the CRC of an empty message, is returned.

Comment: Thank you Mark, this answer introduced me to crcany which solved all problems for adapting crc algorithms for different widths and polys.